# Float bottom - top of each other

Tags: jquery, css, html, drag-and-drop

Hi every one I would want to ask help with css - jquery drag and drop -issue.
I'm familiar with positioning divs to bottom of their containers (position: relative -> position: absolute; bottom: 0;).

Goal: I would want to drag items from storage div and drop those another div and position those items from bottom to top, vertically. Like building a tower (2D) or something. How can I float those items to bottom of new container and top of each others?

Thanks - Jani

```
#drop {
    height:300px;
    background:#EDCCE9;
}
#drag {
    margin-top:10px;
    height:50px;
    background:#B8D8E3;
}
#drag img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.temp {
    display: block;
}
```

---

```
$('.item').draggable({
    containment: 'document',
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function () {
        contents = $(this).html();
        currentValue = $(this).attr('value');
    }
});
$('#drop').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'border',
    accept: '.item',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
        $('#drop .item').addClass('temp');
        $('.temp').removeClass('ui.draggable item');
        $(".temp").draggable({
            containment: 'document',
            revert: true
        });
    }
});
$('#drag').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'border',
    accept: '.temp',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
    }
});
```

---

```
<div id="drop"></div>
<div id="drag">
    <img src="blocks/a.png" width="50px" height="50px" class="item" />
    <img src="blocks/b.png" width="50px" height="50px" class="item" />
    <img src="blocks/c.png" width="50px" height="50px" class="item" />
    <img src="blocks/d.png" width="50px" height="50px" class="item" />
    <img src="blocks/e.png" width="50px" height="50px" class="item" />
    <img src="blocks/f.png" width="50px" height="50px" class="item" />
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than appending the dropped items, try prepending them. This should add them to the HTML flow as the first item. Then you can just have the blocks float normally over each other (either with 100% width of cleared floats). I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but I have to pologise my possible unclear introduction. I think my problem is more css - issue. Difference between jquery "append" and "prepend" is more about item ordering than floating. To be clear, I'll attach my great photoshop illustration to be as clear as possible.

http://www.kalliopaja.fi/example.png


So, my goal is to get all dropped items float bottom top of each other. 

-Jani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is no "float:bottom;" type construction for this. You will have to use position:absolute; as you described.

To do this as you want you can either rely on jQuery to apply the correct `bottom` value (you can do this my *measuring the number of items already in the container*, then *dividing this value by the height of each item*, provided they are all the same size as in the example.)

To count the items in the stack, you can use `.length()` [read here for more](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

**OR**

You can do this with just CSS by using the :nth-child selector. The problem with this, is that it is not fully supported in all browsers (by which I mean IE8 and below) See [can i use it](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) for details.

With this method, you would simply create a list like so, with specified `bottom` values that increased:

```
li:nth-child(1) {
    bottom:0;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
    bottom:50px;
}    
li:nth-child(3) {
    bottom:100px;
}
...
```

this ad nauseum. The issue would then be if you know how many items you need to account for and also that it simply requires a lot of CSS added if you have a lot of items to account for.

---

If they are not all the same size, then you will have to use the jQuery method and, instead of simply counting the number of items already in the stack, you will need to pull the height of them and use that to calculate the proper `bottom` value

Comment: Thank you very much "robooneus", you saved my day! Only one line of code - efficient!

Comment: Here is working code: $('#drop').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'border',
    accept: '.item',
    drop: function(event, ui){
    
     ui.draggable.css('bottom', $('#drop img').length * 50);
     $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
        
     $('#drop .item').addClass('temp');
     $('.temp').removeClass('ui.draggable item');
     
     $(".temp").draggable({
      containment: 'document',
      revert: true
     });
    }
   });

Comment: Glad to help. If it answered your question, feel free to accept the answer. If you need more clarification, let me know and I will update the answer.